# Best practice for managing private files in git repo

Tags: javascript, git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm working on Node.js project that has a file called `config.js`. It has instance-specific information that I don't want to go into source control, so I've added it to `.gitignore` and it's no longer a part of the repo. The problem is: I'm working with someone else on this and we need a way of syncing `config.js` between each other such that

- it's versioned
- it honors the git branch of the project (i.e. the config for `feature-branch-1` might not work for `feature-branch-2`)
- we can resolve conflicts between our respective copies
- the config can be pulled down by Travis during our build/deploy process (it has to be bundled by webpack)

We've tried keeping the file in an S3 bucket, but it wasn't ideal because whoever pushed the file up last effectively overwrote the existing file.

We've also thought about having a private repo with the config and symlinking it back into the main project, but then there's a workflow issue of keeping two repos synced up. And it adds a good deal of complexity to our deployment process, since Travis would have to use an SSH key to pull down the private repo. Not impossible, but wanted to make sure there isn't a more obvious way of managing this type of thing.

If anyone else has worked around this before, would appreciate any tips you might have.

Comment: Putting the file in `.gitignore` but saying you need it versioned are contradictions.  Do you need it in Git, or don't you?

Comment: Actually, they aren't. I need it versioned but not publicly exposed.

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with creating a new placeholder file representing the config file in each branch?  Then, each branch would "know" what his particular configuration is.  The actual config file used in the build could be a different location.  Let Travis copy from the branch config to the real location.